# How to use after_create with Gem Activerecord-reputation-system

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using gem activerecord-reputation-system for voting in my app, and I'm implementing an achievement system on top of it.

One of my achievements is when someone has voted for anything 10 times. I'm trying to either use an after_create callback in the model or observer to trigger the code to see if I should add an achievement.

Problem is that I cannot seem to get any after_create(evaluation) to work. After someone votes for something, I need to see if they should be given an achievement. I want to put this code into a single after create method so that it is not dispersed all over my app.

I've tried making an evaluation model like this

```
 class Evaluation < ActiveRecord::Base 
   after_create :do_something
 end

 class EvaluationObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
   def after_create(evaluation)
     :do_something
   end
 end
```

I've put the models in my models folder. I've gotten to the point where I'm trying to locally install the gem in either the lib or vender folder so I can hook into that way.

I'm using rails 3 with ruby 1.9.3. I know that observers are deprecated in 4, but I'm sticking with them for now.

How can I do this?

Thanks!